# Explicitly define map schema in Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a way to explicitly define a map schema, i.e. define the name and datatype of the key and the value in the map, in Pig Latin?

I've [found that it is possible](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#map-schema) to define the name and datatype of the value in the map, however, I did not manage to define it for the key.

Sample data:

```
[a#1,b#2]
[a#,b#3]
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
a = load 'map_sample' as (themap:map[key:chararray,value:chararray]);
DUMP a;
```

Any ideas?